# Ansible task fails when executed manually with: "skipping: no hosts matched"

Tags: ansible, vagrant, task, virtualbox

I am trying to follow along with a DevOps book (for SharePoint), it describes a way to provision different environments (dev,prod,test) by using vagrant and ansible together an automated, repeatable way to provision multiple boxes for the virtualbox virtualization provider.

`ansible --version` output:

```
ansible 2.7.8
  config file = /Users/username/Desktop/projects/vagrant-ansible-packer-spfarm/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/Users/username/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15 (default, Feb 12 2019, 11:44:53) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
```

I managed to take the first steps, set up the project, provision the one and only DomainController by using the github repo on my mac.

As a next step I would like to execute an ansible task manually by using the ansible CLI to apply some settings on my local deployment (DC) :

- name of the playbook: domaincontroller.yaml
- name of the inventory-file: test.ini
- this is the ansible command to be executed:

```
ansible-playbook -i ansible/test.ini ansible/plays/domaincontroller.yaml --extra-vars="ansible_user='vagrantuser@spdomain.local' ansible_password='Pass@wordX!'" --start-at-task="add admin account to Domain Admins group" -vvvvv
```

As a result i constantly get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkSj1.png) **skipping: no hosts matched**

This is my directory structure and the origin of [this](https://github.com/SharePointOscar/vagrant-ansible-packer-spfarm) project.

Ansible is new to me. I really like how it contributes to the DevOps concept. But I am really struggling on this one, so any help coming from you dev guys would be appreicated! If you need further information to help me out with this issue please do not hesitate to contact me!

Update: I already tried to whitelist the plugins in my ansible.cfg acording to the ansible documentation, but it did not work for me :(
ansible docfile link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/inventory.html

Answer (score 1):

As per Ansible documentation:

> Group names are case sensitive.

Your play defaults `host` directive to `DomainControllers`, whereas in the `test.ini` inventory you have `domaincontrollers` group.

Change something of this, or pass additional extra variable `-e cloud_host=domaincontrollers`